# ASUS hotkeys keys no longer work after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, laptop, windows-8.1, hotkeys

My ASUS VivoBook S500C came with Windows 8 pre-installed, and the hotkeys worked fine, such as volume controls, brightness, etc. However, after an upgrade to Windows 8.1, I can't seem to get it working. I found a suggestion the solution is to install the ATK driver from the ASUS website, then restart the computer, but that doesn't seem to have worked for me.

Comment: Did you first remove the existing atkacpi driver?  Asus recommends doing so before installing the latest.

Comment: @Debra it was a clean install of windows 8.1, so no branded asus software was installed along with it, no drivers etc.  They were all manually installed.

Comment: does ASUS mark the drivers as 8.1 compatible? If not, wait until 8.1 GA and updated drivers.

Comment: Check this page of Asus Support: ATK Package v1.0.0.30 is compatible with Windows 8.1 http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ATK+Package&p=3&s=588